# How to get a column from first table on UNION in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a requirement to fetch all files which is created_by "a@a.com" or shared_to "a@a.com". Below are the 2 tables which is needed to achieve the result.

filter_analysis_store

```
fa_identifier,created_by,case_no
FA000179,a@a.com,01998455
FA000183,a@a.com,01998455
FA000184,a@a.com,02039960
FA000185,a@a.com,02039960
FA000187,a@a.com,02039596
FA000189,a@a.com,02039960
FA000190,a@a.com,02029418
FA000191,a@a.com,02029418
FA000192,a@a.com,02039596
FA000193,a@a.com,02039596
FA000194,a@a.com,02039596
FA000195,a@a.com,01912596
FA000199,a@a.com,02039596
```

share_analysis_store

```
fa_identifier,shared_by,shared_to
FA000173,p@p.com,a@a.com
FA000196,p@p.com,a@a.com
FA000180,r@r.com,a@a.com
FA000198,r@r.com,a@a.com
```

I used "UNION" to come up with a query which gives me the result but I had to give empty string for 2nd query. How to get respective case_no for missing ones?

```
select fas.fa_identifier, fas.case_no as case_no from filter_analysis_store fas  
where created_by like 'a@a.com' UNION 
select sas.fa_identifier, '' from share_analysis_store sas
where shared_to like 'a@a.com';
```

Output of above query

```
FA000184    02039960
FA000183    01998455
FA000193    02039596
FA000199    02039596
FA000180    
FA000189    02039960
FA000195    01912596
FA000185    02039960
FA000194    02039596
FA000190    02029418
FA000191    02029418
FA000173    
FA000192    02039596
FA000198    
FA000179    01998455
FA000187    02039596
FA000196
```

Comment: From where do you imagine these missing values would be coming?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: From `filter_analysis_store` the 1st table. I have mentioned only 2 tables which can be used to solve this problem

Comment: I believe OP wants to union first table and join of two?..

Comment: You want an `and` between two conditions. First condition is calculable from first table and second is from the second table. You don't need union at all. This is a simple `[INNER] JOIN`. The most basic operation with relational data.

Comment: Based on what criteria a record of table `share_analysis_store` relates to a record of table `filter_analysis_store`, since `fa_identifier` is missing from the latter table?

Comment: However your solution attempt suggests that you really want `or` between your conditions, not `and`. Please clarify your question.

Comment: @pozs: The result should include all rows (`fa_identifier, case_no) which is created by or shared to "a@a.com"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a `UNION` to produce rows, *which are created by **or** shared to "a@a.com"*, a simple `LEFT JOIN` could suffice (`LEFT`, because a `fa_identifier` may never even get shared).

```
select    distinct on (fa_identifier) fa_identifier, f.case_no
from      filter_analysis_store f
left join share_analysis_store s using (fa_identifier)
where     f.created_by = 'a@a.com'
or        s.shared_to  = 'a@a.com'
```

`distinct on` is required to produce every `fa_identifier` only once. If that is the primary key in `filter_analysis_store` (or at least a unique key in that), then `select distinct fa_identifier, f.case_no` should be enough.

Comment: Can you help me combine this result with another [question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42529403/how-to-match-a-column-result-from-query-result-to-a-table-column-value-and-get-m)? Need to list all case nos under each project

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
SELECT fas.fa_identifier,
  fas.case_no
FROM filter_analysis_store fas
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT fas.fa_identifier
  FROM filter_analysis_store fas
  WHERE created_by LIKE 'a@a.com'
  UNION
  SELECT sas.fa_identifier
  FROM share_analysis_store sas
  WHERE shared_to LIKE 'a@a.com'
  ) AS lol
ON lol.fa_identifier = fas.fa_identifier;
```