# How to match a column result from query result to a table column value and get more columns from same table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is a continuation of my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42527777/how-to-get-a-column-from-first-table-on-union-in-postgresql/42528074#42527777)

The query is given below, taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42528478/801116)

```
select distinct on (fa_identifier) fa_identifier, fas.case_no
from   filter_analysis_store fas
left join   share_analysis_store sas using (fa_identifier)
where  fas.created_by = 'a@a.com'
or     sas.shared_to  = 'a@a.com';
```

Result

```
FA000173    02029418
FA000179    01998455
FA000180    01757560
FA000183    01998455
FA000184    02039960
FA000185    02039960
FA000187    02039596
FA000189    02039960
FA000190    02029418
FA000191    02029418
FA000192    02039596
FA000193    02039596
FA000194    02039596
FA000195    01912596
FA000196    01912596
FA000198    01995271
FA000199    02039596
```

Another table name is "LOG_METADATA", for simplicity sake I am providing only few columns for this table

```
id,PROJECT_ID,CASE_NO
1,2-0007362,02029418
2,2-0007362,01998455
3,1-5379513,02039596
...
```

So for a given project I need to list all case nos, here project is an array and each project can have multiple case nos if we interpret it visually. Something like below screenshot in UI.
[image]

**Update**

Here is what I am trying out

```
SELECT "PROJECT_ID" AS PROJECT_NO,
  "CASE_NO"
FROM "LOG_METADATA" lm
JOIN
  (SELECT DISTINCT
  ON (fa_identifier) fa_identifier,
    fas.case_no AS "CASE_NO"
  FROM filter_analysis_store fas
  LEFT JOIN share_analysis_store sas USING (fa_identifier)
  WHERE fas.created_by = 'a@a.com'
  OR sas.shared_to     = 'a@a.com'
  ) res USING ("CASE_NO");
```

Comment: `So for a given project I need to list all case nos.` => What is the significance of the above resultset in this question?

Comment: @Utsav: I have listed the resultset only for reference. Content of "LOG_METADATA" table is `id,PROJECT_ID,CASE_NO` where 1 project can have multiple case nos.

Comment: can you add table with the results you wish to get

Comment: why not `select case_no from LOG_METADATA where project_id='2-0007362'` ?

Comment: You can `JOIN` this new table `log_metadata`, `using (case_no)`, and you'll have `project_id` in your query (to filter on, or to select it). I'm not sure what you mean by *here project is an array and each project can have multiple case nos if we interpret it visually*. -- What do you want for output? What parameters do you have to filter on?

Comment: @pozs: I have updated question with a screenshot of how the result of this query might give me list of projects and case nos. Need to combine earlier query with LOG_METADATA table to produce this list

Comment: @Ricky - You didn't answer me yet. Why not use `select case_no from LOG_METADATA where project_id='2-0007362'`?

Comment: @Utsav: This is a continuation question of a previously answered question, where filter or where clause is on "a@a.com" on created_by & shared_to columns from `filter_analysis_store` & `share_analysis_store` table respectively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a sub-select for that, just select your output columns carefully:

```
select    distinct lm.project_id, case_no
from      filter_analysis_store fas
left join share_analysis_store sas using (fa_identifier)
join      log_metadata lm using (case_no)
where     fas.created_by = 'a@a.com'
or        sas.shared_to  = 'a@a.com';
```

If you don't want to a `case_no` appear under multiple `project_id`s, do a `select distinct on (case_no) lm.project_id, case_no` instead. You could control under which `project_id` should `case_no`s appear with `ORDER BY` in that case.

Comment: Here `case_no` in `filter_analysis_store` is different from `"CASE_NO"` in `"LOG_METADATA"` So I am getting `ERROR: column "CASE_NO" specified in USING clause does not exist in left table` error. Modified query according to my DB is `select    distinct lm."PROJECT_ID", case_no
from      filter_analysis_store fas
left join share_analysis_store sas using (fa_identifier)
join      "LOG_METADATA" lm using ("CASE_NO")
where     fas.created_by = 'a@a.com'
or        sas.shared_to  = 'a@a.com';`

Comment: you can use `ON fas.case_no = lm."CASE_NO"` then

Comment: This query works but only for 1 to 1 relation between project_id and case_no, so if multiple case is present under a project_id only 1 case_no is shown. I have asked another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42551183/how-to-get-distinct-column-and-show-one-to-many-relation-in-a-postgresql-query) for this. Can you please help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use `group` by without `distinct`

```
select fa_identifier, fas.case_no
from   filter_analysis_store fas
left join   share_analysis_store sas using (fa_identifier)
where  fas.created_by = 'a@a.com'
or     sas.shared_to  = 'a@a.com'
group by fa_identifier, fas.case_no;
```