# How to get distinct column and show one to many relation in a postgresql query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a UI and server component. In UI I need to show a project_id to case_no relation (one to many) for selection something like below

```
project_id_1
    -case_no_1
    -case_no_2
project_id_2
    _case_no_3
...
```

On server side I have groovy which queries postgresql using below query. This query is not able to give me multiple case_nos for a project_id

```
SELECT DISTINCT case_no,
  project_no
FROM
  (SELECT lm."PROJECT_ID" AS project_no,
    case_no
  FROM filter_analysis_store fas
  LEFT JOIN share_analysis_store sas USING (fa_identifier)
  JOIN "LOG_METADATA" lm
  ON fas.case_no       = lm."CASE_NO"
  WHERE fas.created_by = 'a@a.com'
  OR sas.shared_to     = 'a@a.com'
  OR lm."UPLOADED_BY" like 'a@a.com'
  ORDER BY lm."PROJECT_ID"
  ) tmp;
```

query output

```
0203996,    1-1532464
02029418,   1-53795134
01912591,   1-22432322
0199845,    2-00073626
0203959,    1-2225633
01995271,   1-1755865
01757560,   0-10060         <-- This project has multiple casenos
```

In postgresql there are 3 tables

filter_analysis_store

```
fa_identifier,case_no,created_by
FA000179,   0199845,    a@a.com
FA000183,   0199845,    a@a.com
FA000184,   0203996,    a@a.com
FA000185,   0203996,    a@a.com
FA000187,   0203959,    a@a.com
FA000189,   0203996,    a@a.com
FA000190,   02029418,   a@a.com
FA000191,   02029418,   a@a.com
FA000192,   0203959,    a@a.com
FA000193,   0203959,    a@a.com
FA000194,   0203959,    a@a.com
FA000195,   01912591,   a@a.com
FA000199,   0203959,    a@a.com
```

share_analysis_store

```
fa_identifier,shared_to,shared_by
FA000173,   a@a.com,    p@p.com
FA000196,   a@a.com,    p@p.com
FA000180,   a@a.com,    r@r.com
FA000198,   a@a.com,    r@r.com
FA000203,   a@a.com,    r@r.com
FA000204,   a@a.com,    r@r.com
```

"LOG_METADATA"

```
id,"PROJECT_ID","CASE_NO"
1,0-10000,  01757560
2,0-10000,  02021680
3,1-1532464,0203996
```

Using above 3 tables I need to show project and case relation with where clause on created_by "a@a.com" or shared_to "a@a.com"

Note: There can be multiple case nos under a project_id

Please help me with a query which can accomodate multiple case_nos for a project_id.

Comment: Where does the `0-10060` project_no come from in your example data? A clearer example showing a combination that would result in multiple case_no would help. Also, what is the expected output for such a case? Two rows like (projectA caseA, projectA case B)?

Comment: @systemjack: when a log file is saved it get saved under a project_id and case_no this info is present under "LOG_METADATA" and yes rows like (projectA caseA, projectA case B) is good

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks okay to me. Maybe you're not seeing the results you expect because the `order by` is being applied to the temp table and does not translate in the result. Otherwise there must be some other issue that's not represented in your example data.

For example, this query should give the corresponding result (as long as the case numbers have a matching "a@a.com"):

```
SELECT DISTINCT project_no, case_no
FROM (
    SELECT lm."PROJECT_ID" AS project_no, fas.case_no
    FROM "LOG_METADATA" lm
    JOIN filter_analysis_store fas ON fas.case_no = lm."CASE_NO"
    LEFT JOIN share_analysis_store sas USING (fa_identifier)
    WHERE (fas.created_by = 'a@a.com' OR sas.shared_to = 'a@a.com')
) tmp
where project_no = '0-10000'
ORDER BY project_no

0-10000,  01757560
0-10000,  02021680
```

A query like this might help you see what should result in multiple entries:

```
select PROJECT_ID, string_agg(CASE_NO, ',') as cases, count(*) as count
from LOG_METADATA
group by PROJECT_ID
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: If I do a distinct on project_no wouldnt I get only 1 case no per project?

Comment: No, the way you are using distinct it is looking for distinct combinations of project_no and case_no. "If DISTINCT is specified, all duplicate rows are removed from the result set " (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT)